# why is the jspdf code below printing the data on next page?

Tags: javascript, jspdf

The code below is a snippet of java script which uses jspdf to generate pdf of a html file.i am using HTML renderer which gets the contents from a.jsp file whose id is given as #formcare.

```
function formpdf(){
         var doc = new jsPDF();
         var imgData = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORwuy9B5xcZ3kvrHCTmy'; //image url
              doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 90, 05, 25,25);
        doc.setFont("times");
        doc.setFontType("normal");
        doc.setFontSize("14");
        doc.text(90,35, 'IDeaS INDIA');
        doc.text(50,40,'Reimbursement Form For Employee Day Care');

        doc.setFontSize("12");
        doc.text(70,55,document.getElementById("date").value);
        doc.text(70,60,document.getElementById("name").value);
        doc.text(70,65,document.getElementById("department").value);
        doc.text(70,70,document.getElementById("designation").value);
        doc.text(70,75,document.getElementById("daycare").value);
        doc.text(70,80,document.getElementById("childName").value);
        doc.text(70,85,document.getElementById("dob").value);
        doc.text(70,90,document.getElementById("age").value);           

        var specialElementHandlers = {
              '#editor': function(element, renderer){
                  return true;
              }
        };

        //formcare is my tableId in .jsp file
         doc.fromHTML($('#formcare').get(0), 15, 50, {
              'width': 170, 
              'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        });

         doc.text(10,190,'Note-Employees to ensure that the DAY CARE Center is registered under shop act establishment.');
        doc.text(10,200,'Employees will be responsible towards the safety of the child and company holds no obligation.'); 
        doc.save('form.pdf');           
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per https://parall.ax/products/jspdf HTML renderring is still in its early stages.
It does not support the css and styles.

So if you want document in single page, check with your html/div that you are rendering. try reducing `<br>` or other line breaking tags in your html/div

Answer (score 3):

This problem will get solved if you use bootstrap for styling!